# Undefined is not an object on this.state object

Tags: javascript, react-native, typeerror

I am setting up a React Native App. In this App i am trying to include a reusable Top Navigation Component, which accepts an array of strings and then renders them appropriately. When i am trying to compare the array string to a given string, it throws the following error:

**Unhandeld JS Exception: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.choseTopNavigation'**

Inserting a string to compare works just fine

Setting up state object in constructor

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, ScrollView, FlatList} from 'react-native';
import {Header, TopNavigationButton}  from './components';

type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {


constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { 
    topNavigationOptions : [
      {key: 'Quick Search'},
      {key: 'Person Search'}],
      chosenTopNavigation: 
      "Quick Search",
  };

}

}



renderItem({item}){
  if (item.key == this.state.chosenTopNavigation) {
    return (
        <TopNavigationButton>
          {item.key}
        </TopNavigationButton>
      )
  } else {
    return (
      <Text style = {styles.unchosenTextStyle}>
        {item.key}
      </Text>
    )
  }
}


  render() {
    return (
      <View>

        <Header>Header</Header>
        <ScrollView horizontal = {true}>
          <View style = {styles.navigationContainer}>
            <TopNavigationButton>Quick Search</TopNavigationButton>
            <Text style = {styles.unchosenTextStyle}>Person Search</Text>
          </View>
        </ScrollView>

      <FlatList 
        horizontal
        data={this.state.topNavigationOptions}
        renderItem = {this.renderItem}
      />

      </View>  
    );
  }
}
```

Note This Works

```
renderItem({item} ){
  if (item.key == "Quick Search") { //inserting a string directly works
    return (
        <TopNavigationButton>
          {item.key}
        </TopNavigationButton>
      )
  } else {
    return (
      <Text style = {styles.unchosenTextStyle}>
        {item.key}
      </Text>
    )
  }
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Well the error message is showing that `chose.TopNavigation !== chosenTopNavigation ` so where is the different name coming from?

Comment: Two codes on one screen? Show me the whole code.

Comment: Hey, I have postet more code to clarify my problem, the different names came from a typo error on my side, its now corrected

Comment: data={this.state.topNavigationOptions} =>  data={this.state.topNavigationOptions.key}

Comment: could you try change code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either you can make your function as arrow function like this:

```
renderItem = ({item}) => {
// your existing code
}
```

or you need to bind your function in constructor like this:

```
this.renderItem = this.renderItem.bind(this);
```

Comment: All function of the component should be bind if you want to use "this" inside it.
and an arrow function works because it always maintains the current "this" at the time of assignment. It is all provided in react js documentation : https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#why-is-binding-necessary-at-all

Comment: That is not quite the correct explanation: the reason the OP ran into trouble is that they are passing the method as a *callback to another component*. Only methods passed this way need to be bound, they retain the correct context when invoked directly.

Comment: Yes, other methods does not need binding since it will have correct context...Thanks for correcting..@JaredSmith